# Database caching

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, caching

I have windows server 2008 r2 with microsoft sql server installed.

In my application, I am currently designing a tool for my users, that is querying database to see, if user has any notifications. Since my users can access the application multiple times in a short timespan, i was thinking about putting some kind of a cache on my query logic. But then I thought,  that my ms sql server probably does that already for me. Am I right? Or do I need to configure something to make it happen? If it does, then for how long does it keep the cache up?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's safe to assume that MSSQL will has the caching worked out pretty well =)
Don't bother trying to build anything yourself on top of it, simply make sure that the method you use to query for changes is efficient (eg. don't query on non-indexed columns).

PS: wouldn't caching locally defeat the whole purpose of checking for changes on the database?

Answer (score 2):

Internally the database does all sorts of things, including 'caching', but at all times it works *incredibly* hard to make sure your users see up-to-date data. So it has to do some work each time your application makes a request.

If you want to reduce the workload by keeping static data in your application then you have to implement it yourself.

The later versions of the .net framework have caching features built in so you should take a look at those (building your own caching can get very complex).

Answer (score 1):

SQL Server will handle caching for you, yes.  When you create a query or a stored procedure SQL Server will cache that execution plan and reuse it accordingly. From [MSDN](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms181055%28v=sql.105%29.aspx):

> SQL Server execution plans have the following main components: Query
> Plan The bulk of the execution plan is a re-entrant, read-only data
> structure used by any number of users. This is referred to as the
> query plan. No user context is stored in the query plan. There are
> never more than one or two copies of the query plan in memory: one
> copy for all serial executions and another for all parallel
> executions. The parallel copy covers all parallel executions,
> regardless of their degree of parallelism.
>
> Execution Context, each user that is currently executing the query has a data structure that holds
> the data specific to their execution, such as parameter values. This
> data structure is referred to as the execution context. The execution
> context data structures are reused. If a user executes a query and one
> of the structures is not being used, it is reinitialized with the
> context for the new user.

If you wish to clear this cache you can execute `sp_recompile` or `DBCC FREEPROCHCACHE`

Comment: Execution plan caching and reuse is entirely different subject from the question.

Comment: @NenadZivkovic - Not really, the OP is asking about database caching, a cached execution plan is part of caching and will be used when the OP executes a query.